# Merge object fields aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 3.6 and I have the following data:

```json
[
  {
    "valoresVencimentos": [
      1468.12,
      85.9,
      14.1,
      1899.99,
      241.92,
      869.99,
      696.11
    ],
    "classesVencimentos": [
      "lim_up_1ano",
      "lim_1ano",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "outros",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "a_venc_180d"
    ],
    "classesModalidades": [
      "financiamento",
      "financiamento",
      "curto prazo",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao"
    ]
  },
  {
    "valoresVencimentos": [
      627.29,
      241.92,
      413.47,
      229.74,
      1687.58,
      100
    ],
    "classesVencimentos": [
      "a_venc_180d",
      "outros",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "lim_up_1ano",
      "lim_1ano"
    ],
    "classesModalidades": [
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "financiamento",
      "financiamento"
    ]
  },
  {
    "valoresVencimentos": [
      268.59,
      27.6,
      428.51,
      173.85,
      2301.45,
      100,
      241.11
    ],
    "classesVencimentos": [
      "a_venc_180d",
      "outros",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "a_venc_180d",
      "lim_up_1ano",
      "lim_1ano",
      "a_venc_180d"
    ],
    "classesModalidades": [
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "cartao",
      "financiamento",
      "financiamento",
      "curto prazo"
    ]
  }
]
```

And I need merge fields with same name of each object in the input array, to be:

```json
{
  "valoresVencimentos": [
    1468.12,
    85.9,
    14.1,
    1899.99,
    241.92,
    869.99,
    696.11,
    627.29,
    241.92,
    413.47,
    229.74,
    1687.58,
    100,
    268.59,
    27.6,
    428.51,
    173.85,
    2301.45,
    100,
    241.11
  ],
  "classesVencimentos": [
    "lim_up_1ano",
    "lim_1ano",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "outros",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "outros",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "lim_up_1ano",
    "lim_1ano",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "outros",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "a_venc_180d",
    "lim_up_1ano",
    "lim_1ano",
    "a_venc_180d"
  ],
  "classesModalidades": [
    "financiamento",
    "financiamento",
    "curto prazo",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "financiamento",
    "financiamento",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "cartao",
    "financiamento",
    "financiamento",
    "curto prazo"
  ]
}
```

Currently my aggregation is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { code: '11122233344' }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      valoresVencimentos: '$response.operations.expirations.value',
      classesVencimentos: '$response.operations.expirations.class',
      classesModalidades: '$response.operations.expirations.modality'
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      valoresVencimentos: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$valoresVencimentos',
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ['$$this', '$$value'] }
        }
      },
      classesVencimentos: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$classesVencimentos',
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ['$$this', '$$value'] }
        }
      },
      classesModalidades: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$classesModalidades',
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ['$$this', '$$value'] }
        }
      },
    }
  }, 
])
```

It's imporant to say that ordering should be the same of the input data, so I think that using $group maybe a problem, I already tried a lot of alternatives but my knowledge with the aggregation framework is kind limited, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            valoresVencimentos: [
                { $unwind: "$valoresVencimentos" },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        valoresVencimentos: { $push: "$valoresVencimentos" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            classesVencimentos: [
                { $unwind: "$classesVencimentos" },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        classesVencimentos: { $push: "$classesVencimentos" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            classesModalidades: [
                { $unwind: "$classesModalidades" },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        classesModalidades: { $push: "$classesModalidades" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$valoresVencimentos" },
    { $unwind: "$classesVencimentos" },
    { $unwind: "$classesModalidades" },
    {
        $project: {
            valoresVencimentos: "$valoresVencimentos.valoresVencimentos",
            classesVencimentos: "$classesVencimentos.classesVencimentos",
            classesModalidades: "$classesModalidades.classesModalidades"
        }
    }
]);
```

or you can combine last three `$unwind`s and `$project` into single `$project`:

```js
...,
    {
        $project: {
            valoresVencimentos: { $arrayElemAt: ["$valoresVencimentos.valoresVencimentos", 0] },
            classesVencimentos: { $arrayElemAt: ["$classesVencimentos.classesVencimentos", 0] },
            classesModalidades: { $arrayElemAt: ["$classesModalidades.classesModalidades", 0] }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works just perfect, appreciate the effort, I'll study this aggregation and try to understand what is gone on. 